# Segmentation fault when loading and printing 2d array with random numbers in C

Tags: c, arrays, 2d, fault

When I run the program I get a segmentation fault and I can't figure out why. I also have no idea what I'm doing really.
[image: Here's the code]

Comment: please post your code instead of image...

Comment: `i < 4` --> `j < 4`

Comment: line 27: i < 4 ====>>>>  j < 4;

Comment: Wow I can't believe I missed that a hundred times. Thank you so much!